# PyCharm and source control, the .idea directory, commit or not commit, that is the question

Tags: version-control, mercurial, pycharm

I started a new [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) project and want to version it with [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

There is a .idea directory in the project directory with the following files (and my assumption about whether to version them or not)

- .name - contains the name of the project (version: **yes**)
- encodings.xml - contains defaults(?) for text file encoding (version: **yes**)
- misc.xml - contains something about components, and which Python executable to use (version: **no** - because it hard-codes the path to python.exe)
- modules.xml - contains a list of modules, with the name of the project in them (version: **yes**)
- ProjectName.iml (version: **yes**)
- vcs.xml - specifies which VCS to use (version: **yes**
- workspace.xml - seems to list layout information for PyCharm windows (version: **no**)

Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All files except workspace.xml should be shared, [see the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).

Comment: The FAQ also recommends you ignore tasks.xml

Comment: Based on the updated [KB article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067), you may wish to ignore `gradle.xml` and user `dictionaries`, as well

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you want to share just the code or share the code and project settings too.

For just sharing the code, I add the following to the .hgignore file:

```
^.idea
^.idea/*
/*/.idea
/*/.idea/*
```

The patterns are a bit overkill, but they eliminate all the PyCharm/Workspace stuff.

We primarily use Subversion where I work and I frequently create a Mercurial repo on top of the Subversion checkout to play with possible tweaks and changes.  If you go that route and in particular if you chain the Mercurial repos, then add these entries to the .hgignore file too:

```
^.svn
^.svn/*
/*/.svn
/*/.svn/*
```