# Should I ignore the .idea folder when using PyCharm with Git?

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I read about Git integration in PyCharm, and created a Git repository from PyCharm. I did this in PyCharm because I was hoping PyCharm would know whether the `.idea` folder should be ignored, and if that's the case, it would automatically create a `.gitignore` file with the line `.idea/` in it.

But it didn't, so I assumed that I shouldn't ignore the `.idea` foler. However, I did a quick search and found someone's example `.gitignore` file, [here](https://gist.github.com/yasushisakai/4584653), which clearly ignores the `.idea` folder.

So, my question is, should the `.idea` folder be ignored or not?

Comment: since by and large you can just open a folder as a project in pycharm I would say you certainly dont need it under revision control... that said it wouldn't hurt either(ie no negative repercussions from putting it in git, other than potentially revealing some of your folder structure to the world)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039442/pycharm-and-source-control-the-idea-directory-commit-or-not-commit-that-is-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should the .idea folder be kept under source control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362816/should-the-idea-folder-be-kept-under-source-control)

Comment: Related: [Intellij Idea 9/10, what folders to check into (or not check into) source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041154/3357935)

Comment: **Note:** [IntelliJ's documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) explicitly warns **against** sharing `workspace.xml`. Refer to answers by [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238133/3357935) or [Artem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40092361/3357935) for more detail.

Comment: see which files that [gitignore.io recommends](https://www.gitignore.io/api/intellij) for the IntelliJ platform

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ignoring the whole .idea folder is not necessarily the best idea. There's a number of similar discussions here about this.

- [How to deal with IntelliJ IDEA project files under Git source control constantly changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060727/how-to-deal-with-intellij-idea-project-files-under-git-source-control-constantly)
- [Intellij Idea 9/10, what folders to check into (or not check into) source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro)
- [Should the .idea folder be kept under source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362816/should-the-idea-folder-be-kept-under-source-control)

But I suggest to check the [official FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1186) on this matter.

Comment: **Note:** [IntelliJ's documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) explicitly warns **against** sharing `workspace.xml`. Refer to answers by [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238133/3357935) or [Artem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40092361/3357935) for more detail.

Comment: this is not a good answer. First all the things you provide are links (that can break in the future). Second, it puts the work on the reader than actually being an answer in the answer response spirit of SO.

Comment: This is such a non-answer. To add my two cents I personally exclude the .idea folder and if there's anything specifically within it that others need I will check those files and commit them specifically. I ascribe to the idea that the minimally needed files are better than putting everything in, in regards to git.

Answer (score 37):

> All the settings files in the .idea directory should be put under
>   version control except the workspace.xml, which stores your local
>   preferences. The workspace.xml file should be [marked as ignored by
>   VCS](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-ignored-files.html).
>
> -[PyCharm 2017.3 project documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/project.html#d859391e157)

To explain further, `workspace.xml` contains user-specific workspace preferences. This includes [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708480/3357935), recently accessed files, and cursor position.

Comment: And to make it clear, environment variables could host real passwords, API Keys, etc. Beware!

Answer (score 13):

While sharing your project settings isn't *inherently* a bad idea, there are several exceptions and potential issues you should be aware of.

- The `workspace.xml` file contains various user-specific settings, such as environment variables, cursor position, and Python SDK location.

  - Environmental variables may include private data, such as usernames and passwords
- The `dictionaries` folder contains custom spellings, which can cause conflicts if two developers have the same name.
- The `.idea` folder is PyCharm specific, meaning developers using a different IDE can lead to project desynchronization.
- [IntelliJ's own documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) includes several warnings for specific files that shouldn't be shared.

If you **do** decide to share `.idea`, [IntelliJ's official documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) gives the following advice

> [The .idea] format is used by all the recent IDE versions by default.
> Here is what you need to share:
>
> - All the files under **.idea** directory in the project root **except** the **workspace.xml** and **tasks.xml** files which store user specific settings
> - All the **.iml** module files that can be located in different module directories (applies to IntelliJ IDEA)
>
> **Be careful** about sharing the following:
>
> - Android artifacts that produce a **signed build** (will contain keystore passwords)
> - In IDEA 13 and earlier **dataSources.ids**, **datasources.xml** can contain database passwords. IDEA 14 [solves this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127105#comment=27-765064).
>
> You may consider **not to share** the following:
>
> - **.iml** files for the **Gradle** or **Maven** based projects, since these files will be generated on import
> - **gradle.xml** file, [see this discussion](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55923)
> - user **dictionaries** folder (to avoid conflicts if other developer has the same name)
> - XML files under **.idea/libraries** in case they are **generated from Gradle or Maven** project
>
> Source: [JetBrains - How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839)

Comment: I believe most of these issues will be addressed if you use Jetbrains's gitingore file. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Answer (score 3):

I found some issue when include whole `.idea/` directory into project.

If you push to git repo including `.idea/` directory, and **clone** that project on `other machine` with pycharm, **pycharm can't recognize the project** appropriately.

After **delete** `.idea/` directory, pycharm recognize the project well.

Answer (score 2):

For the freshest of clean starts, don't store `.idea` in version control.

I was doing this for years and it was a hassle setting up for a new IDE/machine as projects became more complicated. I'm happy to have learned how to, safely.

Based on advice above I was going to `.gitignore` just `.idea/workspace.xml`, down from `.idea`, previously.

Though it doesn't show up in PyCharm's explorer, the `.idea` folder is pre-populated with its own `.gitignore` which I can count on being maintained along with the IDE itself. I don't need to explicitly `.gitignore` any of its path, as it takes care of itself.

Here are its contents:

```
# Default ignored files
/shelf/
/workspace.xml
# Editor-based HTTP Client requests
/httpRequests/
# Datasource local storage ignored files
/dataSources/
/dataSources.local.xml
```

If I had anything sensitive in there I would still double check my git commits, but we already do, right?

Answer (score 1):

The .idea/ folder is just the way that JetBrain's stores data. It's in IntelliJ and PyCharm, so, yes, it can be ignored.

Comment: I don't agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516814/pycharm-with-git-shall-i-ignore-the-idea-folder#comment67434330_24516850