# Move .idea folder out of working directory in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm working on a project in pycharm on two different computer. I synchronize my files with the help of github. However everytime I use pycharm it changes files in the .idea folder and I have to be super careful of the order in which I start my computer in order to not prevent the pull (aka if I by mistake open pycharm before pulling, I now have to take the long way around to fix conflicts because it changed the workspace.xml file). Moreover I have to reconfigure the pycharm interpreter everytime I change computer.

I know [this is possible for intellij](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage), but following the instructions for pycharm don't work.

Is it possible to move the .idea folder out of the working directory so I don't have to do all of this?

Comment: read about [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yes that should work thank you very much!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I ignore the .idea folder when using PyCharm with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516814/should-i-ignore-the-idea-folder-when-using-pycharm-with-git)